# How to extract images from a bagfile properly

Tags: ros, bagfile, timestamp, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently I have a bag file which recorded a camera view topic. Now I want to extract the image date with its corresponding time stamp. I am able to get the png form of the image data using the official way provided by ROS wiki, but some frames are missing even if I change the sec_per_frame parameter to be lower than 0.03. I am wondering what is the proper way to extract the image data.

To get the Bag Time, I simply rosplay the bag file and copy the information comes out from the terminal manually. It is okay for short-time recording, but definitely not a possible way for a long-time one. Is there a way I can save the bag time stamp into a text file directly? Is it possible to get the extracted images along with its corresponding time stamp?

Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285942/how-to-extract-images-from-a-bagfile-properly/) by [Teddy_NTU](https://answers.ros.org/users/33489/teddy_ntu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if there is a tool included or available, but if not, the [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) can help you to write a little tool in Python or C++.

---

Originally posted by [Maarten](https://answers.ros.org/users/34054/maarten/) with karma: 206 on 2018-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2